# How to bind several NSTextFields to entries of an NSMutableDictionary in xib?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, binding

It is amazing that the most basic thing to do with binding, goes unanswered in Apple Docs, in Apple sample code, in the dozen or so Cocoa-focused sites and in stackOverflow.

My .xib's FileOwner controller has a NSMutableDictionary property, initialised from a .plist file. Example contents:

```
{
    server =     {
        host = myServer;
        port = 443;
        organization = myOrganization;
    };
    state = "ACTIVE";
    mode = 4;
}
```

I need to bind **host**, **port** and **organisation** to 3 NSTextField instances embedded in a simple view in the .xib, so that the user can edit their values. (port also has a number formatter).

I can't bind directly to the NSMutableDictionary - it's not KVO/KVC compliant on its keys and values.

I tried to use an NSDictionaryController as mediator (bound its contents to my mutable dictionary, but I can't figure out what "controller key" to use. arrangedObjects fails me - there's no array in my contents. "selection" fails me too - there is no selection!

I tried with NSObjectController instead - same thing. No selection, and I can't use "contents" as my controller key.

I want to bind my "host" field to (something).server.host
"organisation" to (something).server.organization 
and "port" to (something).server.port.intValue

Please help. what is something? I'm feeling stupid - this is the most basic binding task I can imagine.

I've done much more complex bindings, but the most simple I can't...

Comment: What kind of object is stored under the ``host`` key? Is it just another ``NSMutableDictionary``? Also, what kind of object is stored under the ``organization`` key?

Comment: NSObjectController and selection should work. Is `server` mutable?

Comment: both "myServer" and "myOrganization" are simple Strings. The dictionary comes, as I said - from a .plist, and there are no subhierarchies except those presented above.